# Is it possible to do Custom Claim Transformations in AzureAD like you can with ADFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, idp

We are attempting to use AzureAD as a IDP for Amazon Web Services and provide the ability for our users to role switch into other accounts / levels of access based on their AD Group memberships.

The following is a link which gives us exactly what we are after using ADFS. Cleverly named AD Groups are transformed into AWS Roles that are passed on as claims.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-federated-authentication-with-active-directory-federation-services-ad-fs/

Specifically, the part that achieves this with ADFS is the Custom Claim Transformations you can do when adding a Role to a Relying Party Trust.

Unfortunately, we have to use AzureAD and cannot use ADFS, at the moment we cannot find a way to use RegEx transformations to get the outcomes we can with ADFS.

Can anyone advise us of an approach or if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

What you can do however, is assign the groups into roles that you define in the apps' manifests.
That way you aren't dependent on magic strings in group names as well.
Note this does require paid licenses as group-based access management isn't available in Free AAD.
On Free, you have to assign user roles to each user individually and a user can only have one role.
With group-based you can assign multiple roles to a user.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps